# Can I charge lead-acid batteries with more current than their rating?

Tags: current, solar-cell, lead-acid, solar-charge-controller

I have a solar charge controller with these specs:

- Type: PWM-Type Solar Charge Controller, 30A, 12V/24V
- Battery type: DC 12V/24V (auto-detect)
- Charge current: 30A
- Discharge current: 30A
- USB output: 5V/2.5A maximum
- Maximum solar input: 23V/46V
- Equalization: sealed 14.4V / gel 14.2V / flooded 14.6V
- Float charge: 13.7V/27.4V
- Discharge stop: 10.7V/21.4V
- Discharge reconnect: 12.6V/25.2V

I aim to use it to charge 2x 12V 7Ah sealed lead acid batteries. I fear that if the charge controller is able to output 30A to the batteries that will exceed the initial current of 2.1A on each of the batteries. Should I get more of the same, or a bigger battery? What size do you think is appropriate?

Comment: Repeated charging at twice the rated capacity of the batteries *will* shorten their service life. Does the controller have a current limiter? If not, add a current limiter to the controller *input*. See https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/analogue_circuits/power-supply-electronics/current-limiter-circuit.php for some example circuits.

Comment: 30A, if the battery will accept it, will (probably) destroy the battery extremely rapidly. The manufacturer will supply a maximum allowed charge and discharge rate. For SLA's iots usually a fcation of their rated capacity (maybe C/10)

Comment: What are the specs of your solar panel(s).